# Can I pass a MutableStateFlow object to a StateFlow variable directly?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from offical sample code [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsViewModel.kt).

I think I can pass `_uiState` to `uiState` directly, so I write Code B, it seems that Code B can work well.

Can I pass a `MutableStateFlow` object to a `StateFlow` variable directly?

**Code A**

```
class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // UI state exposed to the UI
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // UI state exposed to the UI
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. There is one small functional advantage to `asStateFlow()`. It does not simply upcast to a read-only StateFlow, but also wraps it in a read-only StateFlow, such that a receiver cannot cast it to a MutableStateFlow and use its publishing functions. However, this should be considered something that no reasonable code should ever do, because it is asking for trouble to forcibly mutate something that is declared as read-only.

There is no equivalent `asList()` for `MutableList()`, so I'm not sure why they felt Flows need this feature and Collections don't. I can't find any discussion of it. It appeared in the same commit that first introduced StateFlow and SharedFlow.

A secondary feature of `asStateFlow()` is that it permits writing this kind of code more concisely.

```
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

is easier and faster to write than

```
val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState
```

or

```
val uiState = _uiState as StateFlow<InterestsUiState>
```

especially if the type is long or complicated, such as `StateFlow<List<SomeApi.Subtype>>`, for example.